# Regex test for NUMBERS

Tags: .net, vb.net, regex

I have found a `Regex` that test if the text passed to a TextBox is an email.

```
If Regex.IsMatch(email.Text, "^(?("")("".+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))" +  "(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$") _
Then
// True
End If
```

I want to change this, so it will test if the text typed is just `Numbers` ?

How can I do that ?

Comment: A regex to test for just integers is "^[0-9]+$".  Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but what does testing for just numbers have to do with testing for e-mail addresses?

Comment: No, you are not. I found this solution, but I haven't understood it.

Comment: ^ = Beginning of line1.
[0-9] = A range of characters, in this case numbers, from zero to nine.
+ = Match at least 1, but could be more than one.
$ = End of line.

Therefore, the regex ^[0-9]+$ will match any whole line of text containing at least one digit, but will disallow any non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make sure the text contains only digits use a simple `^\d+$` or `^\s*\d+\s*$` to allow some spaces at the beginning and end.

To allow negative numbers: `^-?\d+$` or `^[+-]?\d+$` to allow numbers like `+12`

For decimal numbers: `^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$` (this will allow `0.54` but not `.54`)

This one will allow things like `.54`

```
^[+-]?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246077/simple-problem-with-regular-expression-only-digits-and-commas/4247184#4247184) for a definitive treatment of parsing numbers with regular expressions.